# Why does my server still runs even if I pass any arbitrary name to the Flask class "import_name" attribute?

Tags: flask

I am using flask to create an application, as far as I understand, flask needs the module name to use it to find the root path of the application and find resources on the filesystem. When I pass any name to the Flask() class, it still runs without a problem, so I wonder why does it matter to pass the module name like this for instance `app = Flask(__name__)` while if I typed `app-Flask("anything")` it will still work fine?

Answer (score 0):

The value of what you pass into the initialization of the `Flask` class is used for several things, e.g. find static files and templates.

There are also other reasons, which you can look up in the following blog post:
.https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/why-do-we-pass-name-to-the-flask-class

Comment: Thank you, my question is why even if I pass nay name like this app=Flask("anything"), it still works fine with no problem?